# Sympy generating broken `Piecewise` conditions when simplifying

Tags: python, sympy

## My Code

I effectively have the following reduced code snippet within a larger program:

```
import sympy as sp
print('sympy version:', sp.__version__)

n = sp.symbols('n', integer=True)
expr = sp.Piecewise((0, sp.Ne(n, 3)), (-1/2, True))*sp.Piecewise((2, sp.Ne(n, 0)), (1, True))

print('raw expression:', expr)
print('simplified expression:', sp.simplify(expr))
```

For the simplified expression, I expect something equivalent to:

> simplified expression: Piecewise((0, Eq(n, 0)), (-1.0, Eq(n, 3)), (0, True))

(This potentially could be simplified further to just two branches, but something like that.)

However, my actual output is:

> sympy version: 1.3
>
> raw expression: Piecewise((0, Ne(n, 3)), (-0.5, True))*Piecewise((2, Ne(n, 0)), (1, True))
>
> simplified expression: Piecewise((0, Ne(n, 3)), (-1.0, Ne(n, 0)), (-0.5, True))

## My Problem

The obvious issue is that I did not get what I expected. But more than that, there are blatant logical issues in the simplified resulting piecewise expression; more specifically, in the conditions therein.

The first condition is `Ne(n, 3)`, meaning "the first value will be used when n is not equal to 3". That's fine on it's own.

However, the second condition is `Ne(n, 0)`, which in light of the first condition is completely nonsensical. If n were 0, the first condition would be true and the first branch value would be used, thus it's logically guaranteed that n is not 0 if the second condition is being evaluated.

Worse yet, the last condition is `True` (i.e., "otherwise"), which is the default condition should those of the earlier branches not be met. However, it is logically impossible to reach this branch, since the prior two conditions partition the full space of integers (and `n` is defined as an integer; however, the same problem occurs when `n`'s number type is left unspecified).

(I want to also note that this problem does not exist in either of the original Piecewise expressions before simplifying. While they do use `Ne` for their first branch condition, the second condition is the default `True`, which is perfectly valid.)

## My Question

Can anyone explain this as an intended behavior?

If not, I plan to submit this as a bug to SymPy. I did briefly search [the SymPy issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) for my problem before posting, but I didn't see anything that matched it. I just wanted to double-check here that I'm not overlooking anything first.

Comment: Have never used Symply, but a well written question!

Comment: @narendra-choudhary aside from technical support, emotional support is also appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not "broken" or "nonsensical". It is logically correct, although not presented in the simplest form possible.

The condition `if n == 3 and n != 0` could be simplified to `if n == 3`. There is a difference between "could be simplified" and "is completely nonsensical".

But yes, please report it on SymPy tracker, since the simplification is incomplete; a better result would be `Piecewise((0, Ne(n, 3)), (-1.0, True))`.